# Meaning of killall -0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, process, command

I see from many place the follow command is used to check if a process exists, e.g.

```
killall -0 nginx
```

But from the documentation I can't see anything related to this argument, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**`man kill`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)

> If *sig* is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still
>   performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID
>   or process group ID.

`killall` kill processes by name instead of PID **on Linux & BSD-based systems**.
In other Operating Systems (**Solaris**), the `killall` command is used to terminate all running processes.

Comment: Note: `killall` kills processes by name on Linux and BSD platforms. On other platforms (notable Solaris) is kills all processes (ie stops the server).